# Density function for large numbers with the property $\omega(n)=k\ $?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, density-function

For large numbers, there is a density function which is the probability that a number "near" $n$ is prime. This is $\large \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ This allows to estimate the number of primes in the interval, lets say, $[10^{49},10^{49}+10^{10}]$ without calculating them.

> Do we have such a density function also for the numbers with the property $\ \omega(n)=k\ $ for a given $k$ , where $\ \omega(n)\ $ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ ? For example, can we estimate how many numbers in the interval, lets say, $\ [10^{49},10^{49}+10^{10}]\ $, have exactly $10$ distinct prime factors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\sum_{n \le x, \omega(n) = 2} 1 \sim \sum_{p \le x}\pi(x/p) \sim \sum_{2 \le n \le x} \frac{1}{\log n}\frac{x/n}{\log (x/n)} \sim \frac{x}{\log x} \log\log x$$ and  $$\sum_{n \le x, \omega(n) = k} 1 \sim \sum_{p \le x} \sum_{n \le x/p, \omega(n) = k-1} 1 \sim \frac{x}{\log x} \frac{1}{k!} (\log\log x)^k$$

---

In other words $\sum_{n, \omega(n) = k} n^{-s} \approx P(s)^k \approx (\log \zeta(s))^k$ and $\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(\log \zeta(s))^k$

---

About $[x,x+10^{10}]$  this is a short interval. Those asymptotics are useful to estimate on intervals $[x,(1+\delta) x]$, see the article about the [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Comment: So the density function is $\large \frac{\ln(\ln(n))^k}{\ln(n)\cdot k!}$ ?

Comment: @Peter Define "density function"

Comment: In the case of the prime numbers, we can estimate the number by integrating over $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ , so $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ is the density function (See also the question). Do we have such a function in the case of the numbers with $\omega(n)=k$ ?

Comment: @Peter Sure. But in number theory a density function $f$ for $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ over $\mathbb{N}$ is more a function such that $\frac{\sum_{n \le x,n \in A } 1}{\sum_{n \le x} 1} \sim f(x)$. If $f$ is nice enough then yours is obtained by differentiating $x f(x)$

Comment: Hello reuns, should there be a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ on the right hand side of the first line of your answer?

Comment: @Raven Yes thanks, $\sum_{pq\le x, p\ne q} 1 = 2\sum_{n\le x, \omega(n)=2} 1$